# how to remove "[]" in an json output using php

Tags: php, arrays

how can i convert the following json format

```
[
    [{
        "product_id": 1,
        "name": "Cotton Shirt",
        "sku": "abcdef"
    }],
    [{
        "product_id": 2,
        "name": "Silk Shirt",
        "sku": "csfddef"
    }]
]
```

to like below

```
[{
    "product_id": 1,
    "name": "Cotton Shirt",
    "sku": "abcdef"
}, {
    "product_id": 2,
    "name": "Silk Shirt",
    "sku": "csfddef"
}]
```

I just want to remove the extra square bracket.How it is possible

Comment: This is an dictionary in an array of an array. so while you are parsing you should fetch it according to that.

Comment: the what is the solution for above @ Minaz

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/substr) to return from the first character to the second last character:

```
$input = '[[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}]]';
$result = substr($input, 1, -1);

// $result: [{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}]
```

If the JSON is already an array, then just get the first item:

```
$result = json_encode($input[0]);

// $result: [{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}]
```

Comment: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$json = '[[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}],[{"product_id":2,"name":"Silk Shirt","sku":"csfddef"}]]';

$arrayData = json_decode($json, true);

$newData = array_map(function($data) {return $data[0];}, $arrayData);
$json = json_encode($newData);

print_r($json);
```

Result is:

```
[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"},{"product_id":2,"name":"Silk Shirt","sku":"csfddef"}]
```

**It works, check here: [CLICK!](https://eval.in/549960)**

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: [[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}],[{"product_id":2,"name":"Silk Shirt","sku":"csfddef"}]]

Comment: but you just save into $json='my o/p data';

Comment: i got the json data into an one variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to fetch the internal array from the initial one beforehand, try the following approach using `json_decode` and `json_encode` functions:

```
$arr = json_decode('[[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}]]')[0];
print_r(json_encode($arr));  // "[{"product_id":1,"name":"Cotton Shirt","sku":"abcdef"}]"
```